# Add divs on the SP master page header?

Tags: master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I am new to sharepoint design or design in general and I have just started learning css.

Can someone show me how to insert divs in the master page's header as it is shown in the print screen below?

I made a copy of the seattle.html and I starded modifying it, but I have missed it. I tried to enter a div under the logo, but it is a mess.

Any one can help me on this one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Learning is making a thousand mistakes*

The SharePoint DOM structure is not an easy one, add the whole dynamic part where server or client side code can change layout. And you get a more complex page than any webpage out there.

If you don't know webdesign HTML/CSS then start with the basics, just like you started with a simple colorbook many moons ago.

Start with rebuilding the SharePoint layout with basic HTML/CSS. And make it more complex as you learn.

That way you learn the basics instead of duct-taping HTML/CSS into existing content without any understanding why you are applying ductape.

Note: The text-under-logo is an easy one; if you can't get that right then the other 2 are way out of your league